# Firebase RTDB is not responding in Android app

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

currently I am developing an app that will give you train timestamps when train departure and when the train arrives at the station. Everything is set up but when a user tries to get info from firebase DB about a train at a specific time, then there is my issue, firebase just is not reacting... I tried to log everything, but the logs are empty... here is my code:

```
private void initDatabaseConnection() {
    // Get a reference to your user
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("timestamps");
    Query query = ref.orderByChild("departure").equalTo("8:30");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            TimestampModel trainTimestamp = dataSnapshot.getValue(TimestampModel.class);
            Log.d("timestamp", trainTimestamp.getTrain()+"\n"+
                    trainTimestamp.getArrival()+"\n"+
                    trainTimestamp.getDeparture()+"\n"+
                    trainTimestamp.getRoute().getCityFrom()+"\n"+
                    trainTimestamp.getRoute().getCityTo()+"\n"+
                    trainTimestamp.getRoute().getDistance()+"\n"+
                    trainTimestamp.getRoute().getTravelTime()
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("timestamp", databaseError.getCode()+"\n"+
                    databaseError.getMessage()+"\n"+
                    databaseError.getDetails()+"\n");
        }
    });
}
```

This is the function that is connecting to DB, and tries to fetch node which specific departure field which is in my case 8:30... But how you can see logs are there but there are empty logs when the app is running with that specific tag.

Here are my dependencies on app level:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

[image: Database picture]

Any suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

My best guess is that you're failing to handle the fact that the results are a list, which you can do by looping over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot resultsSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: resultsSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            TimestampModel trainTimestamp = dataSnapshot.getValue(TimestampModel.class);
            ...
```

Comment: Okay so potentially I should use the list of objects to get data from DB correctly. Okay, that's the part that makes sense but when I run my application and I came to an activity that should return me values from DB, logs are empty... I edited the original post with a DB screenshot.

Comment: If you added the loop, I'd expect the result to include the node in your screenshot. But keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll get the best results if *you* run the code in a debugger. For example, if you set a breakpoint on the first line inside `onDataChange`, does it reach that? If so, does the snapshot exist (`call resultsSnapshot.exists()`)? If so, what's its value if you log it?

Comment: Okay so I added resultsSnapshot.exists(), and somehow it passed the debug mode, but still without results... Right after that, I added the breakpoint at the assigning values to the object from the database, but everything goes smoothly... To be honest I am totally confused...

Comment: Also, I forget to mention, that when I look at the monitor rules, there is no traffic between my app and database...

Comment: So do you have a network connection? If you're not sure [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and you should see some extra output in the logcat.

Comment: Yes, I do, I do have a connection because I am fetching city names from external API...

Comment: So far, I have noticed that there is no single request that has been sent to firebase from my app... so the issue is to the connection I guess, is it possible that this is caused because I am getting data in the second activity?

Comment: if you enable debug logging in the way I linked above, Firebase will log what it's doing in your app's logcat output. That should show what's going on.